# PHP / MYSQL - how to structure a log database for 25,000 users

Tags: php, mysql, database-design

I'm dealing with about 25,000 users (employees) spread over 5 divisions in a company.

For all these users, there's an MS Excel spreadsheet in use at the moment. The spreadsheet consists of about 35 columns, logging the employees's daily activities.

Each row is 1 activity and there are on average about 3 activities per day (never ending, meaning the log just grows and grows).

#### MY QUESTION:

I would like to build a database (PHP/MYSQL) that holds the activity log for these users as opposed to the MS Excel files.

1. Should I have a table per user with the 35 columns... leading to a database with 25,000 tables?
2. Or should I store the activities to a 35-sized array, convert it to binary and store it in a blob and build such a table per year... leading to 1 table per year with 25,000 rows?

Comment: It's hard for me to contain how happy I am that you came here to ask this question instead of hacking together a solution.

Comment: what do the 35 columns represent ?

Comment: allow me to be more specific. Here's a couple of columns out of the Excel log table: DATE VEHICLE_ID VEHICLE_TYPE ROUTE_NR FROM TO TOTAL_TIME TOOL_A_TIME TOOL_B_TIME STOPS MILES GAS REMARKS CREW_NAME... My main concern is the size/speed of the database.... what's the most efficient structure.

Answer (score 3):

```
Employee
------------
employeeID
employee_name

Day
------------
dayID
day

Activity
-------------
activityID
activity_name
dayID
employeeID
```

This way you can see an activity for a day
You can see activities for an employee
Can see activity for an employee on a specific day

Comment: polyhedron, thank you for the layout. This means that Employee will hold 25,000 rows, and Activity would hold about 75,000 rows per day (based on 3 activities per day per user). Wouldn't Activity grow to an immense size in a very short amount of time?

Comment: table for the days? sounds mad. http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/Journey_to_the_Center_of_the_Database.aspx

Comment: +1. Flukyspore, of your 35 columns, the ones that have to do with a particular Activity (e.g. `Hours`) then go into the Activity table. The things that have to do with the particular day go into the Day table (e.g. `Holiday`). This way when 5000 of your employees work on July 4th, you can figure out that they worked on a Holiday whether they personally marked that date as a holiday or not. At least one of your 35 columns is probably like that.

Comment: @yi_H: I completely disagree.  Having a days table (as well as  a time table, with one row for each second) makes excellent sense in many applications.

Comment: +1 but you could go even one step further and create a Category table with:  id, title, description  and then have a categoryID in the Activity table.  This would stop from having to write activity names/descriptions over and over again therefore saving space.

Comment: allow me to be more specific. Here's a couple of columns out of the Excel log table: DATE VEHICLE_ID VEHICLE_TYPE ROUTE_NR FROM TO TOTAL_TIME TOOL_A_TIME TOOL_B_TIME STOPS MILES GAS REMARKS CREW_NAME...    My main concern is the size/speed of the database.... what's the most efficient structure. Thx again!

Comment: @flukyspor Either way you are still holding the information in the database. At least by separating by activity, you'll be able to do something with the information. I would assume that the reason you are storing this information in the first place is to get some analytical insight anyway.

Comment: @flukyspor MySQL is able to deal with millions of database entries, that's what databases do.

Comment: I would stick with the activity just like you showed in the above post. If that's all the analytical data you need to extract. Of course, I could think of a thousand things I could do with that data, and design a much more complex database for it, but you know your needs better than I.

Comment: @polyhedron, yes it is for analytical purposes. Every day we want to be able to calculate totals for every employee since they started. I just wasn't sure if it's better to have a database with 25,000 tables or a table with millions of rows. It's a new project as you can tell. Want to structure it right the first time. Thanks again.

Comment: Just about all of fields could be drilled down to another table, most notably vehicle and tools. This way you would be able to track vehicle activity and tool activity.

Comment: @polyhedron OK I'm starting to understand the picture you're drawing. I guess as long as the hardware is in place the size of the database / table is not a problem. Am I correct in this statement: storing the data raw in blobs would reduce the amount of tables, but might be slower and make the processor work harder as the information has to be decoded from the blob and because the totals have to be calculated each time from the raw data.... thus bad idea.

Comment: exactly, not only does it make it harder to process, but it will also make it exponentially harder and more complex to work with it if you ever do decide to drill down for more data

Answer (score 1):

I would use a 35-column table, if you actually use many/most of those fields per activity.

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    uid    INT,
    name   VARCHAR(255),
    ...
);

CREATE TABLE activities (
    uid    INT, // references users.uid
    type   VARCHAR(32),
    date   DATE,
    ... // The 35 activity-related columns
);
```

And then I would partition on time.   Perhaps per-year as you suggested (that would mean up to about 27.4 million rows per table), or per month (about 2.2 million rows per table) if search performance is important, and a per-year table is too big for good performance.

Comment: Ok Thx,  my concern is both size and speed of the database. I'm not really familiar with the max capacity of a database. An Activity table per month... what is the limit of tables a database can hold?

Comment: The maximum number of tables a database can hold varies, but I think it's safe to say that you're far more likely to run into other bottlenecks before that's an issue. Anyway, with the model @Flimzy is suggesting, a decade's worth of data would only result in 120 tables, which is not entirely crazy. With a scheme like this, assuming only the most-recent interval of data is highly relevant, you can eventually push old data into an archival database with, say, one big, slower table per year, while your primary database maintains a year's worth of tables per month.

Comment: @ djacobson, thanks. The archival database would be tough because we calculate totals for an employee for his/her entire career at the company... every day. But I do start to have a clearer picture of how to build the database. I just was a bit worried about having too many tables. Thanks again.

Comment: Actually, I am wrong. The archival table is a great idea as I can make a table with totals per year to use in the every day calculations. Retrieving details from previous years at a slower rate out of the archive is OK as it is a more uncommon operation. Thx again.

Comment: I would recommend reading a book or two about database design.  The one I've read that would be relevant is [The Data Warehouse Toolkit](http://www.amazon.com/Data-Warehouse-Toolkit-Complete-Dimensional/dp/0471200247/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1309903741&sr=8-1). There are probably better books on the topic, but this one gave me enough info to feel like I was able to come up with a core design for our new project, that has served us quite well.

Answer (score 0):

As a rule of thumb, you don't want to create a table for each user. You want to have 1 table, `users`, for that matter, where you'd store IDs, names etc that pertain only to a user model. Then have a separate table would document users' daily activities with a `user_id` column as a reference to the user's row in the `users` table.